# creating a new line for string

Tags: java, function, newline

made a program that counts and outputs users based on user input. I want the program to display the names one below the other with the line break but stuck on how to. the code is below:

```
package uk.ac.reading.cs2ja16.Glen.Stringtest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stringnames {

    public static String[] countNames (String names) {

        // Create Scanner object
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner names1 =new Scanner(System.in);

        // Read a string
        String read= names1.nextLine();

        // Split string with space
        String numPeople[]=read.trim().split(" ");

        System.out.println("The Number of names inputted is:  "+ numPeople.length);


       return numPeople;
    }   


    public static void main(String[ ] args){

        System.out.println("Enter the amount of names you want(make sure you make space for each name):\n");
        String[] namesout = countNames(null);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesout));
    }   
}
```

Comment: you need a for loop: `for(String name: namesout) { System.out.println(name) ;}`

Comment: Also note that in `countNames(null)` the `null` is *strange*

Comment: Warnings are not meant to be suppressed, please close all resources you open, with java7 and above it's as easy as using a [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `countNames` method does not need a parameter, so delete that `String names` thingy in the method declaration. And delete the word `null` in your method call.

Now, you can either use a for loop or use one of the methods in the new Stream API if you're using Java 8.

I'll show you both ways.

For loop:

```
for (String name: namesout) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

the `println` method automatically adds a new line character at the end of the string that you want to print.

Stream API:

```
Arrays.stream(namesout).forEach(System.out::println);
```